# Apply function on nested object with if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I apply the function multiply to the data object for each color key but only if the color key is of type array (the array can be either numeric or of type string)? The data object is of variable "rep" and "parameter" length.

```js
let data = {
  "rep": {
    "color": [1,2,3,5]
  },
  "rep.1": {
    "color": [1,3,5],
    "param1": 0.5
  },
  "rep.2": {
    "color": 1,
    "param1": 0.5,
    "param3": 0.1
  },
  "rep.3": {
    "color": 2,
    "param1": 0.5,
    "param4": 0.1
  }
}

//Function
function multiply(el){
  return el.map(x => x * 2)
}

//Desired output
data = {
  "rep": {
    "color": [2,4,6,10]
  },
  "rep.1": {
    "color": [2,6,10],
    "param1": 0.5
  },
  "rep.2": {
    "color": 1,
    "param1": 0.5,
    "param3": 0.1
  },
  "rep.3": {
    "color": 2,
    "param1": 0.5,
    "param4": 0.1
  }
}
```

Comment: You can use `Object.values(data)` to get an array of those objects. Changing their `.color` will also change the original object. Give it a try, and add your attempt to the question.

Answer (score 0):

try this:-

```
let data = {
  "rep": {
    "color": [1,2,3,5]
  },
  "rep.1": {
    "color": [1,3,5],
    "param1": 0.5
  },
  "rep.2": {
    "color": 1,
    "param1": 0.5,
    "param3": 0.1
  },
  "rep.3": {
    "color": 2,
    "param1": 0.5,
    "param4": 0.1
  }
}

Object.keys(data).forEach(function (key) { 
    var value = data[key]
    if(Array.isArray(value['color'])){
        value['color'] = value['color'].map(function(val){ return val * 2 })
    }
})
```